# Method [vlidate] does not exist error in laravel 5.3 while trying to upload image

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am developing a project in laravel 5.3 where I have to create a 1 feild form to change logo of website my form look like this.

[image]

I do not need to save path in database. I just need to upload file in \public\images\ with name logo and only png files are allowed. so it will be `\public\images\logo.png`

following is the form code.

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

                        @if (count($errors) > 0)
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
                                <ul>
                                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                    @endforeach
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        @endif

                        @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
                            <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </div>
                            <img src="/images/{{ Session::get('path') }}">
                        @endif


                        <div class="box box-info">
                            <div class="box-header with-border text-center">
                                <h3 class="box-title">Basic Info</h3>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.box-header -->
                            <!-- form start -->
                            <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ url('/') }}/admin/change-site-logo" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                                <div class="box-body">
                                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="logo" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Logo</label>

                                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                                            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="logo" name="logo" placeholder="Logo Image">
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="logo" class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>

                                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                                            <img style="width: 200px; height: 50px;" src="https://www.google.com.pk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
                                        </div>

                                    </div>


                                </div>
                                <!-- /.box-body -->
                                <div class="box-footer">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Save</button>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.box-footer -->
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <br /><br />

                    </div>
```

this is Route `Route::post('/admin/change-site-logo', 'adminController@logo_change');`

and controller is as following

class adminController extends Controller
{

```
public function logo_change(Request $request)
{

    $this->vlidate($request, [
        'logo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    $imageName = 'logo.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);

    return back()
        ->with('success', 'Image Uploaded Successfully.')
        ->with('in path', $imageName);
}
```

I am writing first time this kind of code so dont know what to fix. I just know that the error is `Method [vlidate] does not exist.`

Comment: Because method is `vAlidate`.

Comment: I cant understand your comment.. what is this..? is my code 100% correct how to use vAlidate..??

Comment: __PROPER__ method name is `validate` with __A__, not `vlidate`. Call is `$this->validate(`. Do you understand now?

Comment: you are right it was my spell mistake. but now the error is **FatalThrowableError in adminController.php line 98:**
`Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null`